# Programmatic PUT mapping for a type isn't being used?

Tags: nest

I've defined a programmatic mapping for a type following the example in the fluent API unit test (FluentMappingFullExampleTests) like so:

```
_client.Map<SomeType>(m => m
            .Type("mytype")
            ...
```

I then add an instance of SomeType to the index via a call like

```
_client.Index<SomeType>(instance)
```

However, when I go searching for an instance, I don't find any instances of 'mytype'; instead, there's an instance of 'sometype', and a new type mapping has been created for that 'sometype'. I would have expected that the PUT mapping would be honored when I performed the insertion.

Am I not using the PUT mappings the way they should be used? Unfortunately, the unit test doesn't demonstrate round-tripping, so I'm unsure if there's something else I should be doing.

Edit: It bears mentioning that I'm trying to achieve 100% programmatic mapping, here; no NEXT attributes on the type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to handle your use case in my example:

```
//request url: http://localhost:9200/indexName
var indicesOperationResponse = client.CreateIndex(indexName);

//request url: http://localhost:9200/indexName/document2/_mapping
var response = client.Map<Document>(m => m
    .Type("document2")
    .Properties(p => p.String(s => s.Name(n => n.Name).Index(FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed))));

//request url: http://localhost:9200/indexName/document2/1
client.Index(new Document { Id = 1, Name = "test"});

client.Refresh();

//request url: http://localhost:9200/indexName/document2/_search
var searchResponse = client.Search<Document>(s => s.Query(q => q.MatchAll()));
```

Key thing was to mark the `Document` class with `ElasticType` attribute:

```
[ElasticType(Name = "document2")]
public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this helps you.

**UPDATE**

Your comment makes sense. Instead of using `ElasticType` you can change type name inference for `ElasticClient`.

```
var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(uri)
    .SetDefaultIndex(indexName)
    .MapDefaultTypeNames(d => d.Add(typeof(Document), "document2"))

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

So we can remove attribute from `Document` class

```
public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

We don't need also to specify type alias in mapping:

```
var response = client.Map<Document>(m => m
    .Properties(p => p.String(s => s.Name(n => n.Name).Index(FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed))));
```

Comment: Yes, but now the assembly containing your data types must be compiled against NEST. The motivation for using programmatic mappings was to allow us to use POCO objects with no "knowledge" of ElasticSearch at all, and let the PUT mappings handle all of the wireup.
What happens when you remove the attribute from the type?

Comment: Aha! I would have expected supplying the type alias in the mapping would have accomplished this. I'll give it a shot.
Quick question: does this approach handle aliasing multiple datatypes to the same name?

Comment: @AndyHopper Yes, it does.